# Update using 2 inner joins

Tags: sql

I'm trying to update a field in a table based on 2 inner joins, but its not working for me.  I keep getting a syntax error.

```
UPDATE t1
SET t1.value = t3.value
FROM Table1 as t1
INNER JOIN Table2 as t2 ON t1.name = t2.name
INNER JOIN Table3 as t3 ON t2.address = t3.address;
```

Tables structure:

```
name  value
----  -----
bob   ***
tom   ***

name  address
----  -------
bob   100 main st
tom   200 fake dr

address      value
-----------  -------
100 main st  200
200 fake dr  400
```

So the values 200 and 400 are what I'm trying to update the blanks to.

Comment: What does the query return if your simply run a `SELECT t1.name, t3.value FROM ...`?

Comment: Are you using MySQL? SQL Server?...

Comment: What syntax error are you getting?

Comment: I'm using an Sqlite database and the sqlite3 command prompt program.  The error I get is "near '.': syntax error"  I tried the 2 suggested solutions and I get the similar error, but at "t1" and "FROM", respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the following

```
UPDATE table1 t1
SET t1.VALUE =
      (SELECT t3.VALUE
         FROM table2 t2, table3 t3
        WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t2.address = t3.address)
```

Comment: Thanks.  This answer was close.  It turns out the alias at the UPDATE statement doesn't get carried through into the SELECT statement.  Once I figured that out, the update worked, but it copies the same value over to all records.  With just the select it pulls all the values, but once it goes into the update, it only uses the first returned value.

Comment: Ok, I finally got this figured out using.  Apparently you can't use aliases with UPDATE.  This is with sqlite, maybe different with other types.

UPDATE table1
SET value = (SELECT t3.value FROM table2 AS t2, table3 AS t3
  WHERE table1.name = t2.name AND t2.address = t3.address);

Now my next problem is that this updates the entire table so if table3 is not complete, any missing records are turned to null.  I would like this to only update records that are empty.  Any ideas?

Comment: I tried adding another WHERE after the SELECT() but it doesn't seam to pick it up.  No errrors, just nothing changes.  I checked for both a NULL and "", but neither work.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE t1
SET value = t3.value
...
```